# Our dropdown is tabbable even when not expanded

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

We want our dropdown to be tabbable once expanded but non tabbable when not expanded. We have tried tabindex="-1" on the content in the expandable div but that made it non tabbable even once expanded. We have no idea on how to to solve this and would be grateful to any tips.

```
       <div class="container">
            <div class="accordionContent">
                <div class="accordionItem">
                    <button class="itemHeader itemQuestion">
                        Text
                        <span class="itemIcon">
                            <i class="bx bx-chevron-down"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="itemContent">
                        <p class="itemAnswer">
                            <button>Example</button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly what you want to do but If you want to show`div.itemContent` with click on the `button.itemHeader` you can do this :

-set `display:none ;`for `div.itemContent`

-use onclick event for `button.itemHeader`. And call this function :

`function myfunction(){ document.getElementsByClassName[0]("itemContent").style.display=block; }`